# My Asp.net core application show System.stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-2.0

[System.Stackoverflowexception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc2ID.jpg)

```
using fruittyPie.Models.DataRepositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace fruittyPie.Models.Other
{

    public class CategoryMenu : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ICatagoryRepository _catagoryRepository;
        public CategoryMenu(ICatagoryRepository catagoryRepository)
        {
            _catagoryRepository = catagoryRepository;
        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var catagory = _catagoryRepository.Catagories.OrderBy(p => p.CatagoryName);
            return View(catagory);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your CategoryView does not use your _Layout.cshtml - otherwise you got an endless loop here. You are returning a View(catagory) which uses your _Layout.cshtml. Your _Layout.cshtml calls CategoryMenu, which returns a View using your _Layout.cshtml.

If that's not the cause than you should debug into your CategoryRepository.